# Need a more suitable number type in matlab

Tags: matlab, precision

I want to do some statistical calculations in matlab, so my numbers are very small(between 0 and 1) with massive multiplications which makes them even smaller I was using double type for my work but I noticed it only stores 5 digits of my number and for larger numbers it stores the power of 10. So it sure leads to a really big error in the final answers. How can I use more accurate number types? Thanks for the help

Comment: double definitely stores more than 5 digits, are you sure it's not just your display settings. Try type `format long` in the command line and display a number or else open it in the variable editor and double click on the number. What precision do you need?

Comment: @Dan's too polite to say it but: if your understanding of Matlab is so undeveloped that you haven't understood (a) its default representation of numbers, (b) how it presents numbers in the command window and (c) the differences between internal representation and external presentation, you really should spend time getting a good grip on all of these before trying to do anything else with Matlab.

Comment: Mark, dude, relax! It's just a tool not a ticking bomb so I'm trying to learn here!
I understand those concepts but I'm facing an error because of that.
@Dan, I typed "format long" in command line but nothing happened and yes I opened a variable double clicked on it's value and it showed it's real value so I'm guessing that's what you suspected ;)

Comment: no but after typing `format long` you actually have to print a value out to the workspace. So if your variables are in matrix `A` then type `A(1)` with no `;` and I suspect you'll find double has enough precision for your needs? Am I right?

Comment: Aw, yes it does. now it shows all of it's 16 digits thanks ;)

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered working in log-space? represent each number `x = exp( -y )` by its exponent `y`. The exponents `y` now ranges between 0 and `inf` and should be more robust to dynamic range.

Comment: for now my problem has been solved but the thing that you mentioned is so exciting. I'll try that if I ever restricted from digit numbers. Thanks :)